# 引数に使用するファイル名に空白や特殊文字がある際のパス指定

Tags: python, python3, ffmpeg

pythonからffmpegを利用する際に引数としてファイルがあるパスを指定しているのですが、ファイル名に空白や特殊文字が存在する場合に上手く動作してくれません。
ファイル名を文字列で読み込ませるのではなくエンコードしたら良いのでしょうか？
助けて頂けないでしょうか、お願いします。

**エラーになるファイル名**

```
/Users/myname/Desktop/audio/webm/テスト BA feat.ケロッピ（よしりん Cover).webm: No such file or directory

/Users/myname/Desktop/audio/webm/Day in the Life of a Frontend Developer / Coding Streamer.webm: No such file or directory

/Users/myname/Desktop/audio/webm/kero / テスト feat.ケロッピ (hello).webm: No such file or directory

/Users/myname/Desktop/audio/webm/iPad Proの3Dアプリで天狗を作ってみた!! 3Dプリントもできる...驚.webm: No such file or directory
```

**呼び出しコード**

```
import sys
import ffmpeg

title = 'ファイル名'
path = os.path.normpath(os.path.expanduser("~/Desktop"))
audiopath = path + '/audio/webm/' + title + '.webm'
instream_a = ffmpeg.input(audiopath)
        stream = ffmpeg.output(instream_a, '書き出したいパス', audio_bitrate=160000, acodec="aac")
        ffmpeg.run(stream, overwrite_output=True)
```

**OS**
macOS High Sierra

**ffmpegの引数に空白があるとエラーになる。**
https://python5.com/q/tkavzcuz

Comment: 追記された「参考サイト」には対応方法がいくつか紹介されていると思うのですが、あなたは何を参考にしたのかが書かれていません。

Comment: 自分は対応してないのですが、ffmpegの引数に空白があるとエラーが出る。とう事を伝えたいのとサイトの解決策では空白以外は対応できそうになくてもう少し幅広く対応出来る方法があるといいなと思い載せました。

Comment: エラーになるファイル名ですが、2番目と3番目のファイル名には `/` が含まれていますし、4番目はファイル名が途中で切れている様に見えます。実際には存在しないファイルを読み込もうとしているのではないでしょうか。

Comment: 実際にテストで作成して存在します。名前に特殊文字があるのが原因だと思います。それがないファイル名では読み込むことができました。

Comment: Windows ではなく macOS でこういう問題が起きるのは珍しいですね。ffmpeg パッケージが変なことをしているのかもしれません。依然として @cubick さんの回答が有効だと思います。

Comment: @wataru そうなりますと、例えば `/Users/myname/Desktop/audio/webm/Day in the Life of a Frontend Developer /` というディレクトリが存在するのですね？

Comment: それはファイル名に含まれた/でパスの区切りではないです。ややこしくてすいません。

Comment: 動画のタイトルを元にファイル名としているようですが、`/` 等の特殊記号は余計なトラブルを避けるためにもファイル名の方を正規化 (別の文字や記号に変換)した方が無難だと思います。

Comment: @wataru なるほど、それならエラーになりますね。

Comment: そうですね。正規表現を使用して変更します。

Comment: @wataru ええとですね、2番目と3番目のファイルはどうやって作成したのですか？ 正規表現を使っても存在しないファイルにはマッチしませんよ。

Comment: 別のスクリプトで作成してるのでタイトルを正規表現で変えればファイル名も変わります。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

具体的にどう呼び出しているのか分かりませんが、一般的にはファイル名をダブルクォート(`"`)等で括ればうまくいくことが多いです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。`path + '/video/original/' + title + '.' + '.mp4'`こんな感じで文字列にして渡しているのでダブルクォートで括られていると思います。`'`と`"`同じじゃない場合は違うと思います。

Comment: `ffmpeg.input(audiopath)` を `ffmpeg.input('"' + audiopath + '"')` にするという意味です。

Comment: パスが`"パス"`のように囲まれたままエラーになりました。

Comment: @wataru 念の為にコメントしておきますが、ダブルクォート(`"`)を解釈するのは(一般的に)シェルですので、Python から ffmpeg プロセスに引数として渡す場合にはダブルクォートそのもの(`0x22`)として渡されます。

Comment: ffmpegパッケージを使う限り解決不可能かもしれないですね。

Comment: わかりました。正規表現で調節しようと思います。